# Please paraphrase a sentence from "Lord of the Flies"

Tags: paraphrasing

In *Lord of the Flies*, there is a paragraph:

> This toy of voting was almost as pleasing as the conch. Jack started to protest but the clamor changed from the general wish for a chief to an election by acclaim of Ralph himself. None of the boys could have found good reason for this; what intelligence had been shown was traceable to Piggy while the most obvious leader was Jack. But there was a stillness about Ralph as he sat that marked him out: there was his size, and attractive appearance; and most obscurely, yet most powerfully, there was the conch. The being that had blown that, had sat waiting for them on the platform with the delicate thing balanced on his knees, was set apart.

I just can't understand the last sentence:

> The being that had blown that, had sat waiting for them on the platform with the delicate thing balanced on his knees, was set apart.

Could anyone please  paraphrase or interpret that sentence for me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you want us to do your homework, the least you could do is say "Please" rather than Pls.

Comment: Sorry everybody. Just posted my question in a rush. I'm helping a friend study English and came across this problem.I was just not aware of in saying "pls" is not polite enough. I will be more careful. And sorry if I'm asking off-topic questions but I do have an enthusiasm for English.

Comment: @TrevorD: I believe you are applying the rule too strictly. To me, *analysis of English literature* is much deeper than asking for assistance in obtaining the surface meaning of one complex sentence.

Comment: Perhaps Pieter is right, but it would help mightily if the O.P. could elaborate on **what** is confusing about the last sentence, instead of leaving us all to guess. The O.P. might also be interested in the sister site for [ell.SE].

Comment: @I'mforit I think you'll find that ***txtspk abrv8shnz*** are considered pretty insulting, or at least disrespectful, by a fair number of folks in these parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading it as this instead:

> The being that had blown that, [and which] had sat waiting for them on the platform with the delicate thing balanced on his knees, was set apart.

It is unclear why Golding chose to omit the two words I have inserted above, to assist readability, but that is an author's prerogative. As a native English speaker, the meaning comes across easily enough, but I can see how a non-native speaker would struggle.

It's also possible that Golding originally wrote it as:

> The being that had blown that, [that] had sat waiting for them on the platform with the delicate thing balanced on his knees, was set apart.

and an over-zealous type-setter or proof reader omitted the second *that*.

**Update**: from my comment below:
Ralph is "The being that had blown that [the conch]". A conch is a type of large sea-shell that can be blown as a horn. Ralph blew the conch to get the boys' attention and to assemble them (for the election).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I take it that the second "that" in "The being that had blown that"indicates the conch? And "The being" here refers to a specific person who blew the conch? Then how can a conch be blown and what it is blown for by the boys?

Comment: Ralph is "The being that had blown that [the conch]". A conch is a type of large sea-shell that can be blown as a horn. Ralph blew the conch to get the boy's attention and to assemble them (for the election).

Comment: Very clear now! Thanks sooooo much Pieter Geerkens for your patient explanation!!

Comment: That is a very generous offer, but the best thank you is just an up-vote or an acceptance.